# Get value of input inside an input

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form with the following options:

```
    <select name="choices" id="options" onchange="showText()">
    <option value="">Select amount</option>
    <option value="1">100PHP</option>
    <option value="2"> 500PHP</option>
    <option value="3"> 1000PHP</option>
    <option value="4"> 2000PHP</option>
    <option value="5"> 3000PHP</option>
    <option value="6"> 4000PHP</option>
    <option value="7"> 5000PHP</option>
    <option value="8"> 10,000PHP</option>
    <option value="others"> others..</option>
    </select>

    <div class="control-group" id="show" style="display:none;">
```

When the user selects option 1-8, it will display the amount. I've successfully done that through this javascript:

```
    function showText(){
   var value = document.getElementById('options').value;
   if(value == '1'){
   var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
   amount.value = "100";
   document.getElementById('show').innerHTML =
   "<br><br><font size =+1><b>Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;P 100 </b></font>"
   document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block";
   }
   else if(value == '2'){
   var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
   amount.value = "500";
   document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<br><br><font size =+1><b>Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;P 500 </b></font>" 
   document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block";
   }
   //up to option 8
```

Now, when the user selects 'others' it will display another input field. The value that the user will input will be the value option 'others':

```
    else if (value == 'others'){
   document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<br><div class='control-group'><label class='control-label'>Enter Amount</label><div class='controls'><input type='text' id='other_amount' name='other_amount'> ";
   var amount = document.getElementById("other_amount").value;
   document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block";
   }
```

Unluckily, I was not successful in getting the value of the second input to be the value of the first input. I hope you could help! Thank you!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: You should read up about string concatenation in JavaScript. There's really no need for so many `if/else` statements. With string concatenation you can replace all those `if/else` statements will just one or two of them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have both situation on the page already, but hidden, and show the input elements you need when they are needed, instead of changing the DOM for each situation?

Comment: your read the value (other_amount) before it was entered.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can improve your code quite a lot:

```
function showText(){
    var value = document.getElementById('options').value;
    if(value == '-1'){
       //Other
       document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'none';
        var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
        amount.value = value;
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<br><br><font size =+1><b>Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;P " + value + "</b></font>" 
        document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Where you change your html to:

```
<select name="choices" id="options" onchange="showText()">
    <option value="">Select amount</option>
    <option value="100">100PHP</option>
    <option value="500">500PHP</option>
    <option value="1000">1000PHP</option>
    <!-- (...) -->
    <option value="-1"> others..</option>
</select>
```

I'd also suggest adding the "hidden" input for when they choose `others` already in your html, but set it invisible:

```
<div id="hidden" style="display:none;"class='control-group'>
    <label class='control-label'>Enter Amount</label><div class='controls'>
        <input type='text' id='other_amount' name='other_amount' onChange='otherText()'/>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now, when they select `others..` with value `-1` you want to show an input where they can choose their own value:

```
if (value == -1) {
    document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Now we just need the function `otherText()` which shouldn't be a problem:

```
function otherText() {
        document.getElementById('amount').value = document.getElementById("other_amount").value;
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tn9pp8o/2/)

Comment: Hi Guys! Thank you for your feedback. I appreciate it.

Jordumus, I tried your suggestion but seems like its not working. https://jsfiddle.net/oskqk0k4/

Comment: @MariaAlgelikaSantos did you try the fiddle at the end of my answer? Here it is again: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tn9pp8o/2/)

Comment: Oh Sorry, I didn't see the fiddle :) I wanted the second input to appear only when the option 'others' is selected. Also, whatever amount they input on the second input field will be the value of the option 'other' when I click submit. Sorry again, I am not a pro on this. Thank you.